# Creating Azure App Insights using REST API fails requires ROLE

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-rest-api

I am generating API Key for an App Insight. I am using the URL
"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/components/{resourceName}/ApiKeys"

I don't have any clear documentation and I found this from the MS SDK:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/applicationinsights/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ApplicationInsights/src/Generated/APIKeysOperations.cs

However, when I try to generate by mentioning a "name", an error comes in response:

```
{
    "code": "The API Key needs to have a Role",
    "message": "The API Key needs to have a Role",
    "innererror": {
        "diagnosticcontext": "e1f66da1-9247-459e-a519-6426fa1449d1",
        "time": "2019-09-20T07:48:20.2634617Z"
    }
}
```

My POST body is as following:

```
{
    "name": "asimplekeyname"
}
```

Please help if someone has used this specific API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the following properties in the body.

```
{ 
   "name":"test3",
   "linkedReadProperties":[ 
      "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/api",
      "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/agentconfig"
   ],
   "linkedWriteProperties":[ 
      "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/annotations"
   ]
}
```

The three properties correspond the ones in the portal -> your appinsight -> `API Access` -> `Create API key`.

```
api - Read telemetry
agentconfig - Authenticate SDK control channel
annotations - Write annotations
```

You need to select at least one of them, inculde in the request body.

[image]

---

For example, you just select the first one as below.

[image]

The body should be:

```
{ 
   "name":"test3",
   "linkedReadProperties":[ 
      "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/api" 
   ],
   "linkedWriteProperties":[]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I had solved this yesterday by using:
"/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.insights/components/<appinsight-name>/api"
for both the list the list. I found out this worked but was not sure about the possible combinations. Now I know.